# Chebotarev density theorem with certain "bounds"

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a nonconstant polynomial with no rational roots (in particular, $\deg(f)\geq 2$).
By the Chebotarev density theorem, there exist infinitely many primes $p,$ such that $f(x)$ splits into linear terms in $\mathbb{F}_p[x].$

I would like to know if there is a version of this statement which bounds the roots of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ in terms of $p.$ Specifically, let $0<\alpha<\beta<1.$ Then does there exist infinitely many primes $p$ with the property that $f$ splits completely over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and all roots of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ are outside the interval $[\alpha p, \beta p]?$ I don't know the answer even when $f$ is quadratic. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: In this wording, there are still trivial obstructions, e.g. take $f(x)=2x^2-x+1$. The sum of the roots has to be $1/2$, which in $\mathbb{F}_p$ equals $\frac{p+1}{2}$. With $\alpha<\frac{1}{4}$, $\beta>\frac{3}{4}$, this won't work out anymore. But maybe you simply want $f$ to be monic?

Comment: I changed $deg(f)$ to $\deg(f).$ That is proper MathJax and LaTeX usage.

Comment: You are right, it does appear that I need to assume that f is monic, thanks!

Comment: It seems Expectation 1' presented in https://sciendo.com/downloadpdf/journals/udt/12/2/article-p91.pdf would imply this for monic $f$ (although I don't see much beyond heuristics in that paper). The expectation says roughly that the probability for $f$ to split modulo $p$ with roots required to fall into given positive proportions of the interval $[0,p)$ should be positive *as long as* this distribution of roots is not incompatible with the linear relations fulfilled by the roots. When, as here, the ``allowed" positive proportion is symmetric around $0$, there should be no obstruction.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the reference!